# Flash Builder hide class properties from content assist (AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, asdoc

I am extending TextField to create my own implementation of it, and there are some properties & methods I would like to simply remove from use, eg:

```
override public function setTextFormat(format:TextFormat,[...]):void{}
```

I would like now to hide setTextFormat from code hinting, so when, in some other class, I type:

```
var t:MyTextField = new MyTextField;
t.set
```

And hit ctrl+space I only see *setPropertyIsEnumerable(...)* and *setSelection(...)*, no trace of *setTextFormat(...)*. But no matter what I do it still appears, I tried @private metatag in asdoc, as well as some made-up (like @remove, @disable, @ignore, @deprecated). Using *[Exlude]* doesn't work either as, afaik, it works only with mxml.
Is there some way to actually accomplish this task? Or am I forever left with useless and redundant code? Some plugin maybe? (I know I can just leave it as is and don't double methods, but, nevertheless, I'd rather have it my way)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not depending on having the your class extend `TextField` you can wrap the textfield inside a `Sprite` and only "forward" the methods you need. This will still give you the methods of the sprite in the completion, but atleast there'd be fewer.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class WrappedTextField extends Sprite {
        private var _textfield:TextField;

        public function WrappedTextField() {
            _textfield = new TextField;
            addChild(_textfield);
        }

        public function get text():String {
            return _textfield.text;
        }

        public function set text(value:String):void {
            _textfield.text = value;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a solution too which I have used before, but then comes the problem of multitude of Sprite methods. I only mentioned TextField as the case, but I wrote a bunch of my own "mxml-free components" which all extend *Sprite* class, and quite often I would like to remove some Sprite methods, like adding/removing children, which would be then case here. So this solution is a no for me, even though it is a fine contribution.